# SSDT ReportedElement cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-data-tools, always-encrypted, transactional-replication

We get the following error when trying to deploy the SSDT Database project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvDko.png)

We have a DB Project in VS2022 that we enabled AlwaysEncrypted on.  This was working without issue and we deployed using the Excluded Master and Column encryption keys in the advanced properties of the publish profile.

However, while that was still in testing, we added replication to the database and disabled the 'Do not ALTER replicated objects' in the Advanced Properties of the publish profile, which is something we done successfully for other database projects w/o always encrypted.

Now, when we try to deploy, we get the error that the Parameter Name: ReportedElement cannot be null.

I've read that some folks a few years back had this when enabling AlwaysEncrypted, but by itself, it was not an issue.  It appears it the combination of these two things that is causing the issue, but I cannot figure out why.

Anyone have any thoughts, input, suggestions on how to solve this?

Appreciate all of your help.

Nathan